# RPC using EventMachine & RabbitMQ

Tags: ruby, rabbitmq, amqp, eventmachine

I've been starting to play around with RabbitMQ [RPC sample code](http://rubyamqp.info/articles/patterns_and_use_cases/#code_example) provided in AMQP gem doc, trying to write very simple code performing *synchronous* remote calls:

```
require "amqp"

module RPC
  class Base
    include EM::Deferrable

    def rabbit(rabbit_callback)
      rabbit_loop = Proc.new {
        AMQP.connect do |connection|
          AMQP::Channel.new(connection) do |channel|
            channel.queue("rpc.queue", :exclusive => false, :durable => true) do |requests_queue|
              self.callback(&rabbit_callback)
              self.succeed(connection, channel, requests_queue)
            end # requests_queue
          end # AMQP.channel
        end # AMQP.connect

        Signal.trap("INT")  { connection.close { EM.stop } }
        Signal.trap("TERM") { connection.close { EM.stop } }
      }

      if !EM.reactor_running?
        EM.run do
          rabbit_loop.call
        end
      else
        rabbit_loop.call
      end
    end
  end

  class Server < Base

    def run
      server_loop = Proc.new do |connection, channel, requests_queue|
        consumer = AMQP::Consumer.new(channel, requests_queue).consume
        consumer.on_delivery do |metadata, payload|
          puts "[requests] Got a request #{metadata.message_id}. Sending a reply to #{metadata.reply_to}..."
          channel.default_exchange.publish(Time.now.to_s,
                                           :routing_key    => metadata.reply_to,
                                           :correlation_id => metadata.message_id,
                                           :mandatory      => true)
          metadata.ack
        end
      end
      rabbit(server_loop)
    end

  end

  class Client < Base

    def sync_push(request)
      result = nil
      sync_request = Proc.new do |connection, channel, requests_queue|
        message_id = Kernel.rand(10101010).to_s

        response_queue = channel.queue("", :exclusive => true, :auto_delete => true)
        response_queue.subscribe do |headers, payload|
          if headers.correlation_id == message_id
            result = payload
            connection.close { EM.stop }
          end
        end

        EM.add_timer(0.1) do 
          puts "[request] Sending a request...#{request} with id #{message_id}"
          channel.default_exchange.publish(request,
                                           :routing_key => requests_queue.name,
                                           :reply_to    => response_queue.name,
                                           :message_id  => message_id)
        end
      end

      rabbit(sync_request)
      result
    end
  end
end
```

The idea is pretty simple: I want to have a message queue always ready (this is handled by `rabbit` method). Whenever the client wants to send a request, it starts by creating a temporary queue for the response along with a message id; it then publishes the request to the main message queue and waits for a response with the same message id in the temporary queue in order to know when the answer for this specific request is ready. I guess that the `message_id` is somehow redundant with the temporary queue (as the queue should also be unique).

I now run dummy script using this client/server code

```
# server session
>> server = RPC::Server.new
=> #<RPC::Server:0x007faaa23bb5b0>
>> server.run
Updating client properties
[requests] Got a request 3315740. Sending a reply to amq.gen-QCv8nP2dI5Qd6bg2Q1Xhk0...
```

and

```
# client session
>> client = RPC::Client.new
=> #<RPC::Client:0x007ffb6be6aed8>
>> client.sync_push "test 1"
Updating client properties
[request] Sending a request...test 1 with id 3315740
=> "2012-11-02 21:58:45 +0100"
>> client.sync_push "test 2"
AMQ::Client::ConnectionClosedError: Trying to send frame through a closed connection. Frame is #<AMQ::Protocol::MethodFrame:0x007ffb6b9c83d0 @payload="\x002\x00\n\x00\x00\x00\f\x00\x00\x00\x00", @channel=1>
```

There are two points I really don't understand:

1. related to EventMachine: in the `Client` code, why do I have to call `EM.add_timer` if I want my message to actually be published? And why using `EM.next_tick` doesn't work? My understanding is that "everything" is supposed to be "ready" when publish is called here.
2. related to AMQP: why does my client crash due a closed connection for the second request? A brand new EM/AMQP loop is supposed to be created each time a new request is pushed.

There sadly is very few code available online dealing with EM/AMQP so any help will be deeply appreciated!
Any comment regarding the efficiency of this would also be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Digging documentation, I finally found that I actually needed the [`once_declared`](http://rubydoc.info/github/ruby-amqp/amqp/master/AMQP/Queue#once_declared-instance_method) callback to be sure that the queue is ready when the client start using it.

Regarding the connection problem, it seems that, somehow, using `EM::Deferrable` causes issues so the (quite unsatisfactory) solution simply consists in not including `EM::Deferrable`.

```
require "amqp"

module RPC

  module Base

    def rabbit(rabbit_callback)
      rabbit_loop = Proc.new {
        AMQP.start do |connection|
          AMQP::Channel.new(connection) do |channel|
            channel.queue("rpc.queue", :exclusive => false, :durable => true) do |requests_queue|
              requests_queue.once_declared do
                rabbit_callback.call(connection, channel, requests_queue)
              end
            end
          end
        end

        Signal.trap("INT")  { AMQP.stop { EM.stop } }
        Signal.trap("TERM") { AMQP.stop { EM.stop } }
      }

      if !EM.reactor_running?
        @do_not_stop_reactor = false
        EM.run do
          rabbit_loop.call
        end
      else
        @do_not_stop_reactor = true
        rabbit_loop.call
      end
    end
  end

  class Server
    include Base

    def run
      server_loop = Proc.new do |connection, channel, requests_queue|
        consumer = AMQP::Consumer.new(channel, requests_queue).consume
        consumer.on_delivery do |metadata, payload|
          puts "[requests] Got a request #{metadata.message_id}. Sending a reply to #{metadata.reply_to}..."
          channel.default_exchange.publish(Time.now.to_s,
                                           :routing_key    => metadata.reply_to,
                                           :correlation_id => metadata.message_id,
                                           :mandatory      => true)
          metadata.ack
        end
      end
      rabbit(server_loop)
    end

  end

  class Client
    include Base

    def sync_push(request)
      result = nil
      sync_request = Proc.new do |connection, channel, requests_queue|
        message_id = Kernel.rand(10101010).to_s

        response_queue = channel.queue("", :exclusive => true, :auto_delete => true)
        response_queue.subscribe do |headers, payload|
          if headers.correlation_id == message_id
            result = payload
            AMQP.stop { EM.stop unless @do_not_stop_reactor }
          end
        end

        response_queue.once_declared do
          puts "[request] Sending a request...#{request} with id #{message_id}"
          channel.default_exchange.publish(request,
                                           :routing_key => requests_queue.name,
                                           :reply_to    => response_queue.name,
                                           :message_id  => message_id)
        end
      end

      rabbit(sync_request)
      result
    end
  end
end
```